# Masstransit how to get ILifetimeScope in custom filter

Tags: masstransit

I'm using MT version 6.3.2.

I have built a web api which then send the message to consumer queue. I have another process that consumes the message.

Send in api:

```
var endpoint = await Bus.GetSendEndpoint(QueueUri);                        
await endpoint.Send(command);
```

In the consumer process, I use HostBuilder to register autofac

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())                  
            .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>((hostBuilderContext, builder) =>
            {                
                builder.RegisterModule(module);
            }
```

In module I register an IBus instance, I have added a filter like this:

```
builder.Register(cc =>
    {return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rabbit =>
        {
            rabbit.Durable = true;
            rabbit.Host(ServerName, h =>
            {
                h.Username(Username);
                h.Password(Password);
            });
            
            rabbit.ReceiveEndpoint(Queue, rec =>
                {
                    rec.AddPipeSpecification(new MyFilterSpecification<T>());
                    rec.Consumer<TConsumer>(cc);
                });
        });
    })
    .As<IBusControl>()
    .As<IBus>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

I also registered a BackgroundService to start and stop the bus.

In MyFilter, I would like to resolve a dependency registered with InstancePerLifetimeScope in the Send method of the filter.

```
public class MyFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, PipeContext
{

    public Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        context.TryGetPayload(out ILifetimeScope scope);
        // scope here is null
    }
}
```

As above, the scope is null. However later on in the pipeline the same code in my Consumer.Consume() returns a value. I've seen code samples where you can get ILifetimeScope in filter, I'm not sure why it's not working for me.

How can I resolve my dependency in filters? I'm not able to use constructor injection as that only works for singleton dependencies.

Comment: If the answer is unclear, you need to further explain how and from where you are calling Send, I would assume it's from a controller which should have a current scope.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Edited the question to provide more context, thanks.

Comment: You should be using ISendEndpointProvider as the dependency in your API ocntroller, not the bus. Also, you need to use the AddMassTransit configuration syntax for Autofac, otherwise your container registrations will be all wrong. https://masstransit-v6.netlify.app/usage/containers/autofac.html - without this, your scoped will never be configured correctly and it won't work.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson yes, tried using AddMassTransit syntax and scoped filter, works well. 7.0.1 is broken though, need to use latest pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending outside of a consumer, using `ISendEndpointProvider`, you need to create a scope as shown below. The lifetime scope will be included in the payload and available to the filter.

```
public static async Task Main()
{    
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConfigureSend(s => s.UseFilter(new MySendFilter()));
        }));
    });

    var container = builder.Build();

    var busControl = container.Resolve<IBusControl>();

    await busControl.StartAsync();

    try
    {
        using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();

        var provider = scope.Resolve<ISendEndpointProvider>();

        var endpint = await provider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:some-address"));

        await endpoint.Send<SomeMessage>(new { Value = "Hello"});
    }
    finally
    {
        await busControl.StopAsync();
    }
}

class MySendFilter :
    IFilter<SendContext>
{
    public async Task Send(SendContext context, IPipe<SendContext> next)
    {
        var lifetimeScope = context.GetPayload<ILifetimeScope>();

        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually my filter is used on the consumer side, it is in a different process, would this work? And in the consumer process, I don't call builder.Build() or container.BeginLifetimeScope myself, it's managed by .net core. I register IBus in a module, and I load the module in HostBuilder.ConfigureContainer. I'm not sure how to fit the scoped filter syntax in Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq either.

Comment: Saw this issue https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1978, is this related to that issue? Or if I want to get ILifetimeScope, I have to use scoped filter?